# In acumatica, how can I populate a ComboBox with the names of available contacts from a database?

Tags: c#, acumatica

The image below shows the Attention field that I want to turn into a ComboBox (which is the part I know how to do :D). At the moment, the Attention field holds the full name of the main contact for the billing to go to (as shown by the blue label in the image).

[image: Attention field that has to be changed]

This is the information about the Attention field

[image: Attention field info]

However, I would ideally like this dropdown to be dynamically filled with all the available contacts associated with a particular company so that users can select a person of their choosing for the billing.

I was trying something like what is shown below to grab stuff from the database (I was just trying with a demo system so I don't break the main side) but I have no clue how to properly grab a column from a database.

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {

    protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
      SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
      
      List<string> listOfStuff = new List<string>();

      foreach (SOOrder item in PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.OrderQty, Equal<20.00>>>) {
               
         listOfStuff.Add(item.OrderQty);
      }
        
      PXStringListAttribute.SetList<SOOrderExt.usrCuryTotalAmount>(sender, row, listOfStuff.ToArray(), listOfStuff.ToArray());

    }
  }
}
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated :)

Comment: I believe the company field here is a standard text box allowing free-form entry.  To make the Attention pull from contacts, you would have to replace the free-form text box with a selector for a BAccount that has Contacts.  If this is on the SO, for instance, this data is stored in SOContact, which keeps track of what the contact (or override values) were when the SO was created.  You still can populate that way, but you do need a way to pick the BAccount, either replacing the freeform Company or by adding a new field.  Then you will populate with the contact name rather than contact id.

Comment: Oh right ok, thanks Brian! I’ll give this a try and let you know how I go :)

Comment: Took me a while, but after looking at it with fresh eyes after a bit of a break, I finally figured out how to get it working. Thanks @BrianStevens